# Mac/C++/10.8: "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" in dyld?

Tags: c++, macos, linker, valgrind, dyld

I am using valkrie/valgrind on Mac OS 10.8 to find memory leaks in a small testcase command line tool.
While I have been able to locate many problems successfully before, valgrind right now presents the following error to me of which I can't seem to make sense:

```
==69195== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==69195==    at 0x3F68CF: ??? (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==69195==    by 0x11AC2F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==69195==    by 0x8FE13CD9: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69195==    by 0x8FE13FDD: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69195==    by 0x8FE10267: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69195==    by 0x8FE101CB: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69195==    by 0x8FE100B9: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69195==    by 0x8FE01DD8: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69195==    by 0x8FE05ADA: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69195==    by 0x8FE01375: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==69195==    by 0x8FE01076: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
```

Usually valgrind's error traces touch my own code before they descend into library/system calls, 
but in this case the error seems to occur in "dyld::initializeMainExecutable()", which is in a system linker library outside of my control.

Where could I look to fix this - is there another way to make sense of it?

Cheers+thanks y

Comment: How big is your source code?  Can it be posted?  You may have initialization blocks that are the culprit.

Comment: Can you run Valgrind with "--track-origins=yes" option? It should show where the unitialized value comes from.

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies! Unfortunately I can't post the code blocks at the moment, but I did try "--track-origins=yes" - the result was not much clearer.

I am currently assuming this may be a mismatch between valgrind and mac os x (I'm on 10.8.5).

Comment: Ran into a similar valgrind error message but on MacOS Mojave (10.14.2). First thing I'd suggest is upgrading your brew of valgrind if you recently updated your OS. This worked for me in the past, but not this time because valgrind currently doesn't seem to be supported on 10.14.2.